# How to get data between two dates

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Here is my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_mainTable 
WHERE date_issue BETWEEN '1/1/2016' AND DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, '1/20/2016'))
```

but it displays record from 1/5/2015 to 1/18/2016

I hope someone can help me with this kind of problem. Did I miss something in my code?

Comment: If `date_issue` is a varchar, then you have a problem. `"1/5..."` is bigger than `"1/1..."`

Comment: I think it's an issue do with way dates are formatted. Try referencing the dates this way around yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: But my date format is dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: why is this flagged vb .net?

Comment: Coz I'm going to use it in vb.net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the *date_issue* is a **varchar**, it would be a problem with **BETWEEN**.

Try changing the *date_issue* datatype from **varchar** to **datetime**

Comment: nope. its varchar. is there any problem in data type used?

Comment: @JMYu, is it okay if you change the datatype to datetime and run the query again?

Comment: I tried to changed my data type from varchar to datetime and it already works, I just have to trim the data to date only because it also shows time like this 2016-01-04 00:00:00.000

Comment: @Aethlen Thank you so much po! :)

Comment: Try to change from varchar to date. cast(dateissue as date) or convert(date,dateissue,103)

Comment: Type date is not a defined system type. That's what i get when I tried to convert into date.

Comment: @JMYu if you just want the date, try this:  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_issue, 101) AS date_issue, it formats it into mm/dd/yyyy which is also a readable date format in vb.net. You can also try different date formats. refer here: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will select data between the two dates

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_mainTable WHERE date_issue between '2016/1/1' AND '2016/1/20'
```

You can use the [CONVERT() function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) to adjust the format you require.